# Wordpress with Divi: How to integrate CiviCRM contribution pages?

Tags: wordpress, contribution-page

I am trying to set up a contribution page within a Divi layout. At a short glimpse, that looks well, but: this won't work! Instead, I get a lots of CSS problems and JS errors.

I could imagine to get a quick solution using some customizing within the Divi templates.

Or, I return to the original CiviCRM contribution pages, and do the CSS stuff (that is provided by Divi) somewhat manually, in order to create a contribution page looking similar to the Worpdpress Website.

Anybody out there with experience on that?

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to use divi plus a civicrm shortcode?

Comment: I was creating the civicrm shortcode in divi's text mode, and copied that to a text module within the Divi builder (since the civicrm button isn't working within Divi builder). 

So far, I got a contribution page, which "looks" well - however, it doesn't work since there seems to miss some js stuff.

I could give access to the system to somebody who would be able to fix it (as paid work...)

Comment: My guess is that the Divi "text module" doesn't pass its content through the `the_content` filter. You might want to ask in their help forums about that.

Comment: I'm seeing similar. Detlev Sieber, did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes - in the meantime we have a solution, that works perfect :-) 
I will post it after the weekend...

Answer (score 2):

Detlev asked me to answer this question, but to be honest we also insert the CiviCRM contribution page with shortcode in the classic editor. Trying to include the shortcode within a divi module (Divi Text or Code Module) looks nice but doesn't work here as well.

So in detail I create the global site layout with the Divi Theme Builder and set all usefull global settings at the Divi Theme Customizer. Than I activate the classic editor in Divi Theme Options to get the CiviCRM button at the page editor. For style changes regarding the contribution form I use custom CSS as usual.

When I need more Divi Content above or below the contribution content I use the wordpress plugin Simple Divi Shortcode in addition. Therewith I can similarly integrate Divi modules (which I previously build at the Divi library) as shortcode in the classic page editor.

Answer (score 1):

We've worked around this simply by using the default editor instead of the Divi Builder to edit pages with CiviCRM short-codes. Obviously not a real fix for the Divi issue, but we chose to fight other battles instead.